# Not able to print heart shape which print perfectly fine in online compiler

Tags: c++, special-characters

i have been looking online for how to print heart shape in c++. I have found the following code online.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const char heart[] = "\xe2\x99\xa5";
   std::cout << heart << '\n';
}
```

So this code works perfectly fine when run on an online compiler but when i try to run it in my ide code blocks or dev C it doesn't run on any of the two. So what is different in online compilers that this does not work offline.
It just prints `ΓÖÑ`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it not produce the desired output?

Comment: You want to read about _Encoding_, _Unicode_, _UTF8_ and codepages.

Comment: It only prints ΓÖÑ

Comment: It would be good if you point me to the right article

Comment: @Nnnnn there's not _the right article_, it's a complex field. Maybe reading [Joel's Blog post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) helps.

Comment: Unrelated: Lubuntu 18.04, g++7 - The code works ok   a) when run with in my editor (emacs), b) with std::out to a plain LXTerminal 0.3.1.  c) with std::out redirected to another LXTerminal (example /dev/pts/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is not done by your program, it is done by the Environment/Operating system your program runs on.

Read about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to scratch the surface.